# Unable to find the error in my JavaScript for-loop function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, for-loop, if-statement

I wrote JavaScript code which tells you the average of numbers. You enter the numbers by pressing the add button. The added numbers will be shown on the screen. If you don't enter any number, A text "empty string" will be shown and if you enter numbers this message will be not shown and the average of entered numbers will be shown.

But the problem is that, even after entering the numbers still the text "empty string" is shown. And I can't find out why. When I wrote this code without giving user the ability to enter numbers and provide numbers by myself. The same code was working correctly and was showing average but when I added the function to enter numbers... the "average code" start troubling.

Code:

```html
    <body>
        <h2>Averge Function</h2>
        <p>Press the button below to add numbers in the array:<br>
            <button onclick="addNum()">Add</button>
        </p>
        <p id="numInArray"></p>
        <p id="average"></p>

        <!--JS Code-->
        <script>
            var grades = [];

            function addNum() {
                var grade = prompt("Add a number");
                grades[grades.length] = grade;
                document.getElementById("numInArray"). innerHTML =
                "Numbers in array are: " + grades;
            }
    
            var sum = 0;
            if (grades.length > 0) {
                for (index = 0; index < grades.length; index++) {
                    sum += grades[index];
                }
                document.getElementById("average").innerHTML = sum/grades.length;
            } 
            else {
                document.getElementById("average").innerHTML = "Empty string";
            }
        </script>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Among things you should look into

- When code is executed (function declaration, vs execution
- The order of things
- Scopes

An example of how you could rewrite your code with some comments on what has been changed:

```
<body>
  <h2>Averge Function</h2>
  <p>
    Press the button below to add numbers in the array:<br />
    <button onclick="addNum()">Add</button>
  </p>
  <p id="numInArray"></p>
  <p id="average"></p>

  <!--JS Code-->
  <script>
    // Initiate application by declaring variables that should be re-used for everytime addNum will be executed
    var grades = [];
    var sum = 0;

    // Initiate the DOM, changed "Empty string" to "Empty array" while I am nitpicking anyways ;)
    document.getElementById("average").innerHTML = "Empty array";

    // Function that runs only when user creates an input
    function addNum() {
      var grade = prompt("Add a number");
      // Push is a simple way to add something to an array (in this case grade to your grades array)
      grades.push(grade);

      // Removed that for loop for there was no use....
      // Add the grade value (still available from the prompt above) to your sum variable and force it to be a number with parseInt! (If you don't force the prompt value to be a number javascript will take your initial sum 0 and add a string of the user input e.g. "5", javascript will convert that into "05", add another 5 and javascript will store "055", giving some unexpected results)
      sum += parseInt(grade);

      // Update the DOM
      document.getElementById("numInArray").innerHTML = "Numbers in array are: " + grades;
      document.getElementById("average").innerHTML = sum / grades.length;
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Final tip from me would be:
First "design" your application in pseudo code, trying to explain what will need to happen in detail in every step. In this case steps I would identify would be:

1. Initialization of the app
2. Updates after user input

Comment: Thanks pal. Nice tips and also corrected my code. I was thinking why i'm getting unexpecting results. Thanks for writing comments. They helped alot.

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling the `addNum()` function, you are simply adding more elements to your array, and not much else. What you need to do is, add the numbers in `addNum()` again and putting that in the HTML. I've refactored your code. A few pointers:

1. Avoid using `var`, and instead use [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) and [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let), as they help you manage scope of your variable more easily.
2. To add more items to an array use, [`Array.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).
3. I've wrapped your static string `Numbers in array are:` in a `<p>` element that in turn has the `<p>` element to display your numbers.
4. If try to add a string and number in JavaScript, they will simply be concatenated together. Use [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to get the integer value of a variable. This returns `NaN` when the the first non-whitespace character cannot be converted to a number.

```js
const grades = [];
function addNum() {
    const grade = prompt("Add a number");
    if(grade.length > 0){
        grades.push(grade);
    }
    document.getElementById("numInArray").textContent = grades;
    document.getElementById("average").textContent = findSum(); 
}
function findSum() {
    let sum = 0;
    for (index = 0; index < grades.length; index++) {
        sum += parseInt(grades[index]);
    }
    return sum > 0 ? sum / grades.length : "Empty string";
}
```

```html
<h2>Averge Function</h2>
<p>Press the button below to add numbers in the array:<br>
  <button onclick="addNum()">Add</button>
</p>
<p>Numbers in array are: <span id="numInArray"></span></p>
<p id="average"></p>
```